# Redirect wordpress website to a directory using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I've a wordpress installation inside a directory "public_html/mywebsite/"
. My root directory is "public_html/". My domain wwww.mywebsite.com pointed to the root folder "public_html/". Due to some reasons, I can't point the domain to the "mywebsite" folder. But I want to load the website from the "public_html/mywebsite/" directory when wwww.mywebsite.com is called. I tried with htaccess for this implementation. But not working.

In the "public_html/" directory, I put a .htaccess file and added the following code;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mywebsite [L]
```

It redirects the website to the "mywebsite" folder but it returns 404 page of the wordpress website.

I modified the .htaccess of the wordpress directory like this;

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(mywebsite|mywebsite/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the Codex, e.g. change the settings in WP Admin, save permalinks etc?
 https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Method_II_.28With_URL_change.29

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For more security .I made a new folder with a long random name and installed Wordpress there .To redirect visitors to that wordpress folder without them noticing anything in URL, I made a .htaccess file and wrote this in it.

```
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

first part is for security, second part is redirect.I replaced "my_subdir" with the random folder, and replaced "example.com" with my website.

Answer (score 0):

I used the wordpress redirect rule based on the following link and this worked for me.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory